# Execute code after multiple $.get calls have finished

Tags: jquery

How can I execute some code when both these `$.get` calls have completed?

```
if (invoice.is(":checked")) {
    var data = {
        save: 1,
        order_id: order_id
    }

    jQuery.get('http://domain.co.uk/customer_orders/edit/view_pdf', data, function(response) {});
}

var receipt = $(this).parents(".admin_email_preview_container").find("input[name='receipt']");
if (receipt.is(":checked")) {
    var data = {
        save: 1,
        order_id: order_id,
        invoice: 1
    }

    jQuery.get('http://domain.co.uk/customer_orders/edit/view_pdf', data, function(response) {});
}
```

I want to run another `$.get` call only after the above two calls are finished.  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the promises returned by `$.get` in an array and apply that to `$.when()`. Try this:

```
var requests = [];

if ($invoice.is(":checked")) {
    requests.push($.get('http://domain.co.uk/customer_orders/edit/view_pdf', {
        save: 1,
        order_id: order_id
    }));
}

var $receipt = $(this).parents(".admin_email_preview_container").find("input[name='receipt']");
if ($receipt.is(":checked")) {
    requests.push($.get('http://domain.co.uk/customer_orders/edit/view_pdf', {
        save: 1,
        order_id: order_id,
        invoice: 1
    }));
}

$.when.apply(requests).done(function() {
    // both $.get calls have completed, run other code here...
    $.get('/other-endpoint');
});
```

Note that I tidied your code slightly by the consistent use of `$` instead of `jQuery` (if you need to prevent contamination of the `$` variable, use a closure), I moved the objects directly in to the `$.get` calls to make it easier to read and also removed the redundant empty callback functions.

Comment: Glad to help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply